# UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiwindow

I'm receiving the following error when a user is in `MFMailComposerViewController` and presses the **Home** button:

> [UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on > without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.

I have looked around the forums and some other people have experienced this error in different circumstances, but there is no solution.

I have set `shouldAutorotate` to this in all the View Controllers in the app:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
                                  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ||
           interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Any news regarding this question? I have the same issue

Comment: Is it official that there is still no solution to this problem?

Comment: I just had the same error, and it was because I was calling `transitionContext.completeTransition(true)` twice by accident in `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning -animateTransition(_:)`. I doubt this is exactly the issue you're having, but it might be related to calling something related to the presentation of the mail view controller? You, or anyone else having this issue, might want to investigate the UIKit transition-related code surrounding view controller transitions that are performed before this log.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have redundant calls to dismiss keyboard, UIActionSheet and etc.

I had the same problem and solved by changing my way to dismiss the keyboard. I found this below post to be the most helpful one

[Unknown error [UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotation]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368592/please-help-unknown-error-uiwindow-enddisablinginterfaceautorotation)

Comment: Put here part of the content of the link because it become unavailable.

Comment: Actually, @laeroah my be right. It looks like inconsistency with calls to view controllers animation or with `resignFirstResponder` things for any kind of `UITextField` or `UITextView`.