# UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated: without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation

Tags: ios

-`[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:]` called on

```
<UITextEffectsWindow: 0x7fabf14d7de0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fabf14d8ac0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fabf14d82a0>> without matching
-beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

I got this when tapping on a text field in a collection view cell.
And when received Keyboard will show notification, I've written the code -

```
self.descriptionCellHeight = xxx;
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdate];// My intent is to recalculate the cell height when prompting keyboard. It works on other text field in a table view cell, it doesn't work on a collection view cell.
```

I wonder why is that.

Comment: Do you want to change the height or the yPosition of you cell?

Comment: @LoVo the key point here is `[self.tableView beginUpdates];[self.tableView endUpdate];` will prevent the keyboard to show if the text field is in a collection view cell.

Comment: Ah now i get it, what about calling the tableview animation in keyboardWASshown?

Comment: @LoVo the keyboard will show up and get dismissed immediately after that.

Comment: I had this happen when dismissing the keyboard interactively with a tableview that has default cell. This is might be a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368592/unknown-error-uiwindow-enddisablinginterfaceautorotation.